# ReportViewer 10 renders a blank screen when used in ASP.NET application

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ssrs-2008

I have a .NET application written in VS 2010, target .NET version is 4.0, using the ReportingServices version 10 control. My SSRS server is SQL Server 2008 Enterprise. Web Server is IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2008 R2 64-bit. I did review [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623695/reportviewer-10-0-on-iis-7-5-not-rendering) but it did not resolve my problem.

The application has been working fine since August of last year until about a week ago. Of the five reports included in the application, three still work but two have stopped working. When the RS control appears on the screen, I get the message it is Loading with the twirly green circle. Eventually, that stops and all I have left is the control header without a report. I can see the parameters are properly populated and I can click on View Report but I never get the actual report on the screen.

I did go to the Report Manager (SSRS) site and verified the report works as expected. It does take about five minutes to generate, which the users are fine with. They understand it is chewing on a massive amount of data to generate the report. I can't do snapshots since they want the data real-time every time they run it.

I assume there is some sort of timeout, somewhere, but can't find it. One thing I did find is that the Loading message goes away before SQL Server has completed generating the result set for the report, which leads me to believe the timeout is in the application itself. Since other reporting applications on the same web server are working fine (different applications all part of the same web site), I'm not convinced the timeout is there. I did find a Timeout tag for the ServerReport section and set it to a ridiculously high value with no success. I have also re-published both report and application with no success. Code is included below. Thanks for your help in advance!

Relevant code in the .ASPX page:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>

<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>

<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer" runat="server" Width="100%" 
    ProcessingMode="Remote" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="8pt" 
    ShowCredentialPrompts="False" SizeToReportContent="True" ShowParameterPrompts="true"
    ShowRefreshButton="True" ShowFindControls="True" ShowPageNavigationControls="true" Height="500px">
    <ServerReport DisplayName="Cluster Net Change" ReportPath="/Enrollment Reports/Cluster Net Change" 
        ReportServerUrl="http://reports.pinnacle.inside.pisd/reportserver" Timeout="6000000" />
</rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

Relevant sections in web.config:

```
<assemblies>
  <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices.Protocols, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
  <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
  <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
</assemblies>

<buildProviders>
  <add extension=".rdlc" type="Microsoft.Reporting.RdlBuildProvider, Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
</buildProviders>

<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
</httpHandlers>

<handlers>
  <add name="ReportViewerWebControlHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
</handlers>
```

Comment: I did some additional work on the SQL side and got it all working again. I still need to know how to change the timeout so it will wait longer before giving up.